# Are Helidon's Oracle Cloud Infrastructure dependencies present in Maven Central?

Tags: maven, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, helidon

I'm messing about with [Helidon's OCI Object Storage integration](https://github.com/oracle/helidon/blob/master/integrations/cdi/oci-objectstorage-cdi), and it has a dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.oci.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>oci-java-sdk-objectstorage</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

But I don't see [any reference to that artifact in Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.oracle.oci.sdk%22%20AND%20a%3A%22oci-java-sdk-objectstorage%22).

Where can I find these dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like these libraries [are still not in Maven Central](https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/issues/25).  The [workaround](https://helidon.io/docs/latest/#/extensions/04_cdi_oci-objectstorage#_prerequisites) (building and installing the relevant Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Java SDK components by hand) is documented in the Helidon documentation, which I forgot.  Time for more coffee.